# Output results to text file

Tags: powershell

Thanks to @Theo yesterday I got my script to work and do exactly all the things I wanted.  So now have a lovely menu system, options etc.

But I've decided - like a charm I wanted to do a little more!

So part of what is happening is finding files and renaming them.  Theo's example was best:

```
D:\The Old Man and his dog.mp4   → D:\Old Man and his dog (The).mp4
D:\A Nightmare on Elm Street.mp4 → D:\Nightmare on Elm Street (A).mp4
D:\I, Robot.mkv                  → D:\Robot (I).mkv
```

What I wanted to do is change from output to screen the results.  To a log file of changes made, and preferably update the file and add or make a new log file every time the script runs.  Just in case I ever need to find something or check what happened - I've got something to refer back to!

Below is the code I've used but not to happy with to display the results.

```
Start-Sleep -s 5
cls
Write-Output "
```

Ok then, `$filter` and `$rename` has now been searched and changed.

With a total of

```
(Get-ChildItem | ? {$_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).Addminutes(-10)}).Count
Write-Output "files being changed.


"
pause
cls}
```

I would like to get a better display result, i.e.

> xx Files have been successfully update
>   xx Files failed.
>   Please see log for details.

And then look in the log file and see something like:

`Log1.txt`:

> D:\The Old Man and his dog.mp4 successfully Changed to D:\Old Man and his dog (The).mp4
>   Total of 1 /1 files successfully changed

I'm thinking of `Compare-Object` and `Out-File`, so maybe

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content c:\user\documents\List1.txt) $(Get-Content c:\user\documents\List2.txt) > c:\user\documents\diff_output.txt
```

But for some reason I cannot get my head around this idea and figure out where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly, extending on my previous code, you could do this:

```
$rootFolder = 'D:\'                                                   #'# the root folder where the files and subfolders are
$logFile    = 'D:\renamed_{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss}.txt' -f (Get-Date)  #'# the file to log to, including the current date

# create an array of words that start the file name and should be moved towards the back
$words = 'The', 'i', 'a'

# create a regex pattern where all possible words are separated by the regex OR (|) sign
$re = '^({0})[ ,]+' -f ($words -join '|')

# create two integer counter variables
[int]$success, [int]$failed = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $re } | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = '{0} ({1}){2}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace $re), $matches[1], $_.Extension
    try {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -ErrorAction Stop -WhatIf
        Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "Successfully renamed '$($_.FullName)' to '$newName'"
        $success++
    }
    catch {
        Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "Rename failed for file '$($_.FullName)'"
        $failed++
    }

}
# write summary
$total   = $success + $failed
$summary = "Total of $success / $total files successfully changed`r`nTotal of $failed / $total files failed"
# output summary to the log file
Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "`r`n==========================================================="
Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $summary

# output summary on screen
Write-Host "`r`n$summary`r`nPlease see '$logFile' for details." -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Using the same three examples will output this on screen:

> ```
> Total of 3 / 3 files successfully changed
> Total of 0 / 3 files failed
> Please see 'D:\renamed_2019-09-18 12_07_01.txt' for details.
> ```

and the log file will contain:

> ```
> Successfully renamed 'D:\A Nightmare on Elm Street.mp4' to 'Nightmare on Elm Street (A).mp4'
> Successfully renamed 'D:\I, Robot.mkv' to 'Robot (I).mkv'
> Successfully renamed 'D:\The Old Man and his dog.mp4' to 'Old Man and his dog (The).mp4'
>
> ===========================================================
> Total of 3 / 3 files successfully changed
> Total of 0 / 3 files failed
> ```

Comment: That's blinding, it works exactly as I dreamed.  Thanks, clearly you're very knowledgable and I do appreciate the help.

I know this sounds silly.  It works and does what I wanted - but I am trying to learn from this.  So I've tried to play with your code and make a different version but although it runs, it generates no results.  I've now worked on this for about 90mins plus and can not see my error.  Would you mind showing my mistake?

Comment: $drive = read-host "
Please enter the foleder location where files need to edited"

CD "$drive"

$filter = Read-Host "
Please enter the phrase to search for, and replace"

$rename = Read-Host "
Please enter the phrase/Text to replace with"

$logFile    = 'Option 3 - Renamed {0:ddMMyyyy HHmm}.txt' -f (Get-Date)  

[int]$success, [int]$failed = 0

cls

Write-Host "You want to find '$filter' and change to: "$rename" " 

pause

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$Filter*" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $rename } | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = ($_.BaseName -replace $rename),

Comment: $matches[1], $_.Extension
    try {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -ErrorAction Stop
        Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "Successfully renamed '$($_.FullName)' to '$newName'"
        $success++
    }
    catch {
        Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "Rename failed for file '$($_.FullName)'"
        $failed++
    }

}
# write summary
$total   = $success + $failed
$summary = "Total of $success / $total files & folders successfully changed`r`nTotal of $failed / $total files & folders failed"
# output summary to the log file
Add-Content -Path $logFile

Comment: -Value "`r`n==========================================================="
Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $summary

# output summary on screen
Write-Host "`r`n$summary`r`n

Please see '$logFile' for details.

" -ForegroundColor Yellow

Comment: @daffyduck As for learning, it is always good to experiment on a copy of working code, but please do **not** add code (except for oneliners) in comments because it will become unreadable. Having said that, I can see you are relying on user input with `Read-Host`. That is always tricky bc you never know what (if anything) the user enters and if used with `-match` or `-replace` operators you should at least `[regex]::Escape()` them. There is much more incorrect in your code like the `Where-Object` clause. Think what you are comparing against what.

Comment: @daffyduck Next, you create `$newName` without a template string to format to, so that will result in an invalid or empty filename. 
Also, have a look at what `$logFile` contains. In your code it is definitevely not a valid file path.
My advice is to keep doing alterations, but take it one step at a time. Include lots of `Write-Host` lines and `WhatIf` switches on every step.

Comment: thanks for the advice and suggestions.  I'll sit down and at it with fresh eyes probably over the weekend.

$logfile contains no results.

[regex]::Escape() is not something I've any knowledge of so I think I'm going to focus around that next.  and then perhaps come back to making these changes.  Thanks for the help and pointers!  Believe it or not I am enjoying it!

Comment: @daffyduck That's the spirit!